# Search file for zip code in bash grep/sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Trying to find each line containing a zip code using sed/grep
can't figure out what im missing, and cant find anything like what i am after.

zip code is 4 digits.

Comment: `can't figure out what im missing` how about adding the code you tried so that issue can be spotted... and add sample input/output

Comment: added code, figured it out right after. did not have any code to go from so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `egrep "[0-9]{4}"` .

The `[0-9]` part matches any character between '0' or '9' (that is, the  numeric characters).

The `{4}` part states that the previous rule should happen fout times in a row. (That is, numeric-numeric-numeric-numeric).

`egrep` is the `grep` version that supports regular expressions.

Comment: so whats the difference from egrep and grep then in this situation?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/508881/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-pgrep-egrep-fgrep

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '\s[0-9]\{4\}\s' matches 4 digits which start and end with a whitespace.
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: yes it is, but think the first(second) answer is more correct :)

Comment: @moody Do you want to capture this? `This is a postcode4567ofthat` or this `This is a postcode 4567 of that`. Without whitespaces, you will capture first one also.

Comment: have not set any requirements for specification so, but i was just missing the part for the 4 numbers :)

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE, wasn't far away, quite simple... grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
probably is other ways as well.